# how can i get the information inside react js object

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

how can I access the name inside the object and put it inside a variable

```js
const newItem = [...items].filter((item) => id === item.id);
const comments = newItem.price;
console.log([newItem.price]);
```

I tried this one but didn't work, console says undefined

Comment: Create a working snippet to demo this.

Comment: It is really unclear what you want since the title asks about extracting values from an object, but your code snippets is filtering an array. `newItem.price` will be undefined in all likelihood. Question needs a lot more clarity and include what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

The filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

[filter() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

You can get price by usign the below way.

```
const newItem = [...items].filter((item) => id===item.id);
const comments= newItem[0].price;
console.log(newItem[0].price)
```

Comment: If an empty array is returned then `newItem[0].price` will throw a "cannot access X of undefined" error. I also don't think the question is answerable just yet since the title, description/question, and code snippet don't agree at all.

Comment: @DrewReese, If you want to handle undefined error, You can handle it easily using ?. 
`newItem[0]?.price`

Comment: Are you asking? Yes, that is one way to keep the code from breaking. I'm just pointing out your code has a bug.